# How do make items stick to right in inline-flex

Tags: css, tailwind-css

[image]

```
 <div class="inine-flex flex-col justify-end gap-2 space-y-2 outline md:flex-row">
```

How do I make that download all button stick to right?

Comment: Did you try `float-right` or `fixed right-0` ?

Comment: Please post all code relevant to your question. So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Since its flex, use `justify-content:right;`

Comment: I would add a `margin-left: auto` to the button

Comment: If the parent container is a flex container, just use justify-content: flex-end.